# Client side encryption: Javascript vs Java Applet vs Adobe Air

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, web, air

I'm considering to implement client side encryption in a web project that I am developing.
The goal is to ensure that data is "private" to the user and the server has no way to decrypt it.

At first I thought I could use use some **Javascript** library to encrypt/decrypt the data in the browser before sending it to the server, however [articles like this one](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) convinced me that javascript is still fairly "weak" when it comes to cryptography and security.

I am considering now to use **Java Applets** (my codebase is in Java, it would be a natural choice) as a "bridge" between the JS code and the server side code, however I can see some pitfalls:

> 1. nobody (in my experience) is using Java applets anymore and that might be for a good reason
> 2. Users need to install/upgrade Java (sometimes it can be an unpleasant operation)
> 3. Tablet/smartphone support is non-existent (but this could be "solved" by providing a native app)
> 4. [It seems that browsers tend to block Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/browser_activate_plugin.xml) and make it difficult to enable it

Another possibility could be to adopt **Adobe Air**. Again, I can see some troubles:

> 1. Users need to install/update it
> 2. There seems to be some support for mobile, however I wonder if it would work in a mobile browser (my guess? no)
> 3. Is it still actively used/supported out there? I noticed that Adobe has open sourced Flex and donated it to Apache, which might
>      imply scarce interest in Flex's future...

What could be the best solution? Are there alternatives (maybe *Google Dart*?)? What are the best practices for client side encryption?

Is javascript truly out of the picture?

---

EDIT: some reasons why I would like to implement client side encryption (asked in the comments):

1. Users will store confidential data and would like to keep it as private as possible.
2. If the database is compromised, there is a smaller chance of data leakage
3. I really value privacy and want to provide this as a feature to my users
4. Better protection against insider attacks

Comment: Some reference reading: http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3305Q4J6AVNQK/Amazon-S3-Client-Side-Authenticated-Encryption ... this question may get closed as "calling for opinion".  Try posting in Software Recomendatins

Comment: I'm not skilled enough in security to truly help you, but I think you could elaborate on 2 points. 1) Who are you procting against what/who ? (e.g. why don't your client trust you ? What don't you trust in your infrastructure, ...) ?  2) If client data is private and you can't read it... are you sure you need to send it anyway ?

Comment: The goal is to understand what is the state of the art in client side encryption, not simply to get some opinions. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Its a very interesting question, but at this point in time I do believe that a 'pure' client side web application is not a good fit for the requested security measures. It would be an interesting thing to have as part of standardized browser integration through HTML 5. An extension to for example allow data to be encrypted before transmission using a private/public key that the user owns.

Comment: @Gimby I also thought about a browser extension, however they are not really "portable" (even less than a java applet or adobe air). However this is indeed an option.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about creating your own extension, but it is indeed "a" solution ;) Perhaps even a viable solution, it all depends on your target audience. If its for business application purposes, perhaps yes. If it is for public consumer purposes, you won't convince many people to install an extension to use your webapp.

Comment: @Gimby you're right, I slightly misinterpreted what you wrote ^^

Comment: I believe LastPass does client-side decryption (like in your situation, they can't read customers' passwords), as does ProtonMail. You could take a look at their products to get some clues about how to do it. (I'm obviously not suggesting you rip off copyrighted code, but I think reading the code to find out its general approach is okay.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Java WebStart, which can simply run as a sandboxed Java application once installed. For the mobile support, I guess that would mean creating an app within the appstores. For Android the business logic and crypto is relatively simple to accomplish; the Android and Java API are largely similar.

JavaScript is not fully out of the picture; JavaScript *without SSL* is though. There are enough other challenges though, such as the lack of a random number generator from standardized API's. Note that whatever solution you try, the user must place some trust in your services. As you control the code, you also control what happens within that code.

Don't know about Air, other than that I would not install it without a darn good reason.

Comment: Trusting your code is a bit (not necessarily hugely, but enough) different from trusting that your servers will never be hacked and data compromised. The easiest way to ensure that information won't be compromised in a leak is to ensure that you don't have it in the first place.